# How do I interrupt the destroy method before it puts up the confirmation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my view file I have

> %td= link_to 'Destroy', fund_subfund_path(@fund, subfund), :method =>
>   :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }

My controller has

> ```
> def destroy
>   @subfund = Subfund.find(params[:id])
>   fund_id = @subfund.fund_id
>   nickname = @subfund.nickname
>   if @loans.empty?
>     @subfund.destroy
>     respond_to do |format|
>       format.html { redirect_to fund_path(fund_id), notice: 'Subfund ' + nickname + ' was destroyed.' }
>       format.json { head :no_content }
>     end
>   else
>     respond_to do |format|
>       format.html { redirect_to fund_path(fund_id), 
>         notice: 'Subfund ' + nickname + " has Loans, so can't be destroyed." }
>       format.json { head :no_content }
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

The redirects and messages work fine. My problem is that even if @loans is not empty and the @subfund.destroy action is not carried out, the "Are you sure?" confirmation still appears.

How do I intercept this method *before* the confirmation message?

I did try link_to_if as an alternative, but that still displays "Destroy" as an inactive link, which I think would be confusing to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baylor Rae's is a good answer, in particular it checks in realtime if there are any loans.

You might also consider a simpler alternative: when you render the page where the delete link_to is, you might put or not the delete button based on wether there are or not loans.

I do not speak HAML either, but I'm pretty sure is strightforward to include your %td= link_to in an `if ... else ... end` statement.

If the button should not be rendered you can write a text that explains why the user cannot delete that object. This way it's easy for the user to understand the situation, rather than having to click on the delete link to find out you cannot perform that action.

Cheers,

Comment: This answer worked great for me. I added an else line so that if the subfund has no loans the 'Destroy' link appears, and if it has at least one loan then instead it displays how many loans it has.